# How to see the code under xLanguage standard class?

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

I need to see the code under the class `xLanguage`.
In order to understand how to get the Language *Description*,

```
xLanguage::languageID2Description(str languageID) // method
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a Kernel function, so you can't see the source code (practically).

Languages can be added/removed so I suspect it retrieves that description via the actual filesystem (likely somewhere in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Dynamics AX\60\Server\[aos_name]\bin\Application\Appl\Standard`) OR it's stored somewhere in the modelstore database.

If you are asking to see the code for the purposes of simply retrieving `Description` for some other purpose (external system?), then the simplest thing would be to just create your own static table and load languages/descriptions into it for retrieval.

```
LanguageTable       languageTable;
MyTable             myTable;

ttsBegin;
while select languageTable
{
    myTable.languageId  = languageTable.LanguageId;
    myTable.description = languageTable.languageDescription();
    myTable.insert();
    info(strFmt("Inserting %1: %2", languageTable.LanguageId, languageTable.languageDescription()));
}
ttsCommit;
```

Comment: Also see the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dynamics/ax-2012/system-classes/gg949085(v=ax.60))

Comment: Thanks @FH-Inway for your extra info.

Comment: Thanks @Alex Kwitny, there is any way to check the Language Description stored?

Comment: @ulisses I don't think so practically. That's why I said to create your own custom table and just load it once and use it for reference. Languages/descriptions aren't really ever changing except maybe by AX version. The description could be stored in a varbinary field that you could maybe interpret, similar to how this guy did it (second answer) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54206405/what-are-the-possible-values-and-text-description-for-batch-job-status-in-ax-201 .

Comment: Thanks @Alex Kwitny